# Who was the first actor/actress who made the move from Adult to Non-Adult movies full time?

Tags: acting-career, adult-movies

This question is obviously inspired by Sasha Grey's [entrance](http://moviesblog.mtv.com/2008/10/16/steven-soderbergh-looks-to-porn-star-sasha-grey-for-the-girlfriend-experience/) into mainstream moviemaking in Soderbergh's "The Girlfriend Experience".

**Was there a Adult actor or actress who made such a move successfully?**

If so, **who was the first known one?**

To reject (probably numerous) unsuccesful attempts, I'm ONLY looking for the actor/actress that:

- Were legitimate full time Adult ones, meaning roles in at least 2-3 movies that would reasonably be classified as Adult Movies, ideally from known studio.
- After that, for a period of at least 5 years, derived their main income from mainstream movies (or TV or live theater), appearing in at least 3-5 ones.
- Have not had any acting roles in Adult Movies after that.

To avoid offending people, please refrain from linking to adult-themed sites in your answers - most actors are listed on either IMDB or Wiki, I would hope; or from listing - never mind including pictures from adult movies they were in.

Comment: I believe that Brent Corrigan is currently treading this path.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth - not only does your comment repeat what an existing answer stated - it isn't even correct, as (as the answer notes) the example doesn't fulfill the question's requirements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My clear choice for winner here is [IMDB: Traci Lords](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000183/), who resents her "ex-adult star" title.
If she's not the first to leave the industry, she's clearly the most famous.

Answer (score 10):

This probably shouldn't count because it doesn't meet your first criterion, but I think it is notable. Sylvester Stallone's first film was a (soft-core) adult film called [The Party at Kitty and Stud's (1970)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065904/) (a.k.a. Italian Stallion). He only did it because he was very desperate for money so I wouldn't call him an adult actor.

Comment: Yes, I would agree. It wasn't a "career" for him, just a one-off temp job.