# TV series about a suburban town digging up a space ship?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, mystery

It was on TV in the US about 10 years ago, it is a mystery with some sci-fi/horror elements.

The people in a suburban city start acting weird (possessed/influenced).  They would go out at night and dig, later it is discovered that they were digging out some kind of alien spaceship.

Anyone know the name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You call this a TV series, but you could mean a TV movie miniseries of a Stephen King novel [Tommyknockers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106156/combined). It starred Jimmy Smits of NYPD Blue fame (and LA Law) and Marg Helgenberger, then just off the TV series China Beach, and lately from CSI.

Here's the description from IMDB:

> *A buried UFO slowly turns local inhabitants into gizmo-building alien mutates [sic].* (mutants is correct)

It also starred Traci Lords who I submitted in this earlier movies.stackexchange question [Adult to Non-Adult movies full time](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/1069/304).

Interesting IMDB movie citations:

> Marg Helgenberger's mother, Kay, appeared in the movie (her only IMDB acting credit), as did Alan Rosenberg, Marg's then-husband; they divorced in 2010. A real family affair.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, this description also fits the 1958 BBC serial "Quatermass and the Pit," or its 1967 movie remake, which was released in the U.S. as "Five Million Years to Earth".